# How to do grouping in lightning:datatable?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I was able to find posts on grouping in apex:pageBlockTable but not with lightning:datatable. My goal is to have the lightning look&feel for the table and also do the sorting on the client-side without using external libraries.

Really appreciate it if someone can push me in the right direction.

Comment: Please provide more context on what you are trying to achieve, some sample code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm trying to create a lightning datatable which should look like a report with ROW GROUPING. I can add the code but it's going to be a regular lightning:datatable example code.